# Enabling Autolinking in Slate.js editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, text-editor, slate.js

i am new in js and i wanted to Enabling Autolinking in Slate.js editor.
for example.
when we type [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in any editor it convert it into the clickable link.

i want that when a enter a link and press space it should be converted into the Clickable link .

here is my current code
all other SHORTCUTS wroks fine but when i try to insert Link it does not show anythings.
the reason is i dont know how to merge link in Childern.
link validation logic is fine .
all i need is when i insert link and press space it should show me a clickable link..

`````
import { Slate, Editable, withReact } from 'slate-react'
import {
  Editor,
  Transforms,
  Range,
  Point,
  createEditor,
  Element as SlateElement,
  Descendant,
} from 'slate'
import { withHistory } from 'slate-history'

const SHORTCUTS = {
  '*': 'list-item',
  '-': 'list-item',
  '+': 'list-item',
  '>': 'block-quote',
  '#': 'heading-one',
  '##': 'heading-two',
  '###': 'heading-three',
  '####': 'heading-four',
  '#####': 'heading-five',
  '######': 'heading-six',

}

const MarkdownShortcutsExample = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Descendant[]>(initialValue)
  const renderElement = useCallback(props => <Element {...props} />, [])
  const editor = useMemo(
    () => withShortcuts(withReact(withHistory(createEditor()))),
    []
  )
  return (
    <Slate editor={editor} value={value} onChange={value => setValue(value)}>
      <Editable
        renderElement={renderElement}
        placeholder="Write some markdown..."
        spellCheck
        autoFocus
      />
    </Slate>
  )
}

const withShortcuts = editor => {
  const { deleteBackward, insertText } = editor

  editor.insertText = text => {
    const { selection } = editor

    if (text === ' ' && selection && Range.isCollapsed(selection)) {
      const { anchor } = selection
      const block = Editor.above(editor, {
        match: n => Editor.isBlock(editor, n),
      })
      const path = block ? block[1] : []
      const start = Editor.start(editor, path)
      const range = { anchor, focus: start }
      const beforeText = Editor.string(editor, range)
      console.log("This is testin",validURL(beforeText))  
      const type = validURL(beforeText)?"link":SHORTCUTS[beforeText]

      if (type) {
        Transforms.select(editor, range)
        Transforms.delete(editor)
        const newProperties: Partial<SlateElement> = {
          type,
        }
        Transforms.setNodes(editor, newProperties, {
          match: n => Editor.isBlock(editor, n),
        })


        return
      }
    }

    insertText(text)
  }

  editor.deleteBackward = (...args) => {
    const { selection } = editor

    if (selection && Range.isCollapsed(selection)) {
      const match = Editor.above(editor, {
        match: n => Editor.isBlock(editor, n),
      })

      if (match) {
        const [block, path] = match
        const start = Editor.start(editor, path)

        if (
          !Editor.isEditor(block) &&
          SlateElement.isElement(block) &&
          block.type !== 'paragraph' &&
          Point.equals(selection.anchor, start)
        ) {
          const newProperties: Partial<SlateElement> = {
            type: 'paragraph',
          }
          Transforms.setNodes(editor, newProperties)

          if (block.type === 'list-item') {
            Transforms.unwrapNodes(editor, {
              match: n =>
                !Editor.isEditor(n) &&
                SlateElement.isElement(n) &&
                n.type === 'bulleted-list',
              split: true,
            })
          }

          return
        }
      }

      deleteBackward(...args)
    }
  }

  return editor
}
const validURL=(str)=> {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}
const Element = ({ attributes, children, element }) => {
  console.log("777",attributes, children, element)
  switch (element.type) {
    case 'block-quote':
      return <blockquote {...attributes}>{children}</blockquote>
    case 'bulleted-list':
      return <ul {...attributes}>{children}</ul>
    case 'heading-one':
      return <h1 {...attributes}>{children}</h1>
    case 'heading-two':
      return <h2 {...attributes}>{children}</h2>
    case 'heading-three':
      return <h3 {...attributes}>{children}</h3>
    case 'heading-four':
      return <h4 {...attributes}>{children}</h4>
    case 'heading-five':
      return <h5 {...attributes}>{children}</h5>
    case 'heading-six':
      return <h6 {...attributes}>{children}</h6>
    case 'list-item':
      return <li {...attributes}>{children}</li>
    case 'link':
      console.log("Inside")
      return   <a {...attributes} href={element.url}>
      {children}
    </a>

    default:
      return <p {...attributes}>{children}</p>
  }
}

const initialValue: Descendant[] = [
  {
    type: 'link',
    url:'',
    children:[{ text: '' }],
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [
      {
        text:
          'The editor gives you full control over the logic you can add. For example, it\'s fairly common to want to add markdown-like shortcuts to editors. So that, when you start a line with "> " you get a blockquote that looks like this:',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'block-quote',
    children: [{ text: 'A wise quote.' }],
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [
      {
        text:
          'Order when you start a line with "## " you get a level-two heading, like this:',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'heading-two',
    children: [{ text: 'Try it out!' }],
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [
      {
        text:
          'Try it out for yourself! Try starting a new line with ">", "-", or "#"s.',
      },
    ],
  },
]

export default MarkdownShortcutsExample````
any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance
`````